# Can meaning indeterminately be said to be indeterminate?

Tags: meaning, concept, kripke

James Ross has given several reasons as to why he believes thought (and formal thought especially) is determinate. Among these, and under a formulation put forward by the contemporary philosopher Edward Feser in "Kripke, Ross and the Immaterial Aspects of Thought", is the argument that a rejection of determinancy presupposes a conception of determinancy itself, so that in denying thought to be determinate one must understand what it is for thought to be determinate.

However, to 'understand what it is for thought to be determinate' requires that such a thought is itself determinate (or so the argument goes). For the strength of the argument against determinancy of thought is in its actual denial of determinancy being attributed to thought. But if neither 'determinancy' nor 'thought' are determinately understood then it seems that no determinate argument can be made for the indeterminancy of thought itself. Hence, there is no actual reason to accept any argument given for the indeterminancy of thought, or any argument *period* for that matter. But this is obviously a view that cannot be allowed, since it is itself arrived at through argument. Hence it is self-defeating, along with arguments given against the determinancy of thought. Therefore, by *reductio ad absurdum*, thought is indeed determinate.

Is this analysis correct though?

Comment: Can you explain the terms a bit more. What exactly is the thesis under dispute? I'm not sure what it means for thought to be determinate or indeterminate. I understand indeterminacy about the truth of propositions, and that we can think propositions that are indeterminately true, i.e. "That man is bald" when pointing to some man whose hair is a borderline case for baldness. I could also think "That man is borderline bald." But what does it mean for thought to be indeterminate or determinate?

Comment: Sure. Meaning in the modern conception is often considered 'indeterminate' if a word(s) can refer to multiple things and if there is nothing in the word itself that suggests it refers to one thing or another. 'Thought' is assumed in Ross and Fesers' analysis to be distinct from our grammar and our words. For thought to be 'indeterminate' is largely for a given thought to not be about any one thing more than another. Thought is thus indeterminate insofar as it is determined by meaning, which is indeterminate insofar as it is determined by the words we use.

Comment: The argument given by Ross and Feser then is largely one against this behaviorist metaphysics which reduces thought and meaning to words or material behavior alone.

Comment: Ok, that's a bit more clear. I'd still like to know which of these two is their thesis:
No thoughts are indeterminate. - or - Not all thoughts are indeterminate? I'm also not sure what the connection is to materialism. Whether or not mental content can be indeterminate seems quite independent of what the nature of mental content is.

Comment: Your analysis seems plausible but it's hard to tell whether it is correct or not without looking at the text. Can your provide a reference?

Comment: I looked through Ross's paper, and he seems to misunderstand both  indeterminacy and arguments for it. Indeterminacy doesn't refer to ambiguous reference, nor do the arguments appeal to limitations of "physical processes", or identifying thoughts with words, or even to empiricism. They also make no assumptions about the nature of thoughts, and work the same whether those are material or immaterial. Here is a short paper that describes and compares Quine's and Kripke-Wittgenstein's indeterminacy arguments https://uni.hi.is/opj/files/2011/02/OPJ-quine-kripke-wittgenstein.pdf

Comment: @Conifold It seems that you either didn't read Feser's paper (which specifically addresses that Ross is not intending by his denial of Quine's behaviorism/physicalism the relevance of a 'private' or 'hidden' fact) or you simply are choosing to be far too critical of Ross to the point that you are inflating the argument that Ross is giving. Ross is not proposing anything (such as a 'hidden' fact). He is rather approaching the skeptical problem noted by both Quine and Kripke as a reductio ad absurdum of reducing all thought to the indeterminate singularities which constitute our experience.

Comment: One might say the only 'hidden fact' here is the depth of modern philosophy's unchecked assumptions. Ross does not assume that one can only explicate meaning as 'hidden' phantasms (or 'qualia') or physical things able to be spoken about in public terms. Both such options are singular and indeterminate. He rather upholds a more complicated, platonic conception of the mind in which a determinate or universal aspect of reality can actually be grasped. So it seems that to peg Ross as accepting some 'hidden fact' is to simply beg the question against him since that is hardly his argument at all.

Comment: Also, the paper you presented largely doesn't answer to the objection raised by Ross. As John Searle notes, for Quine and Kripke's argument to even take place it must be the case that at least insofar as the argument goes, the terms 'rabbit' and 'undetached part of rabbit' (in the case of Quine) and 'plus' and 'quus' must be determined. Indeed, Kripke himself understands this: "the word 'plus' denotes a function whose determination is completely precise" (Kripke 1982).

Comment: I don't follow where 'hidden facts' fit. Here is Ross:"*The difficulty is that, in principle, such truth-carrying thoughts cannot be wholly physical... Now we need reasons why no physical process or function among physical processes can determine "the outcome" for every relevant case of a "pure" function*". Ross's "objection" replaces "truth" with "determinacy" in the old anti-sceptical argument, and fails for the same reason. Scepticism about X argues incoherence of a conventional notion of X, contra Searle this can take place without assuming X true or even meaningful.

Comment: Hidden facts come into play in light of what I understood to be the point of the article you posted a link to, which essentially tried to unify Quine and Kripkes' thoughts about meaning. Kripke attacks the notion that 'hidden facts' can bear any meaning for the fact that they are just as indeterminate as public facts, and indeed more so since they are void of any community. For Ross, he isn't suggesting determinate thought is either about physical, 'public' facts *or* about'private' qualia. His argument doesn't hold either to be determinate, and so Quine and Kripkes' division isn't exhaustive.

Comment: And again, it doesn't seem clear that you understand Ross's argument. Ross is not speaking about truth-conditions. He is granting whatever those he is criticizing grant, and this is 1) the indeterminancy of the physical and 2) the manner in which it is able to be discerned that a given X is indeterminate rather than determinate. If you suggest that #2 can be avoided you essentially make the argument that no argument can be given, which is self-defeating. *This* is Ross's argument. You hold that a given X can be doubted without X possessing a determinate meaning, but this is an untenable view.

Comment: For X to be indeterminate is for X to not possess a singular meaning, in which case it is not doubt or skepticism that one experiences regarding X but plain ignorance or confusion.

Comment: Ross: To argue about X you have to presuppose that it has "determinate meaning". Sceptic: Why? Ross: Because I do. Sceptic: I am not you. If no argument can be made on Ross's terms so much the worse for Ross. In principle, sceptic does not owe any account of meaning without "determinacy", he is a sceptic, only showing that it is fiction. But Kripkenstein is generous, in "sceptical solution" meaning is use, arguments are part of linguistic practice, and their conclusions are assertible within it, not "determinate". It is pointless to dispute it though, the sceptical argument stands without it.

Comment: @Conifold Ross's answer to the skeptic is hardly 'because I do'. He devotes a large portion of work to stating exactly why thought must be determinate, among these being the impossibility of argumentation without determinate meaning (including any argument the skeptic could give). Ross assumes, with John Searle and Thomas Nagel, that to possess a doubt about a given X is to understand what X is and to face a fear of error about said X. One might ask the skeptic, what marks a distinction between doubt and ignorance if not an understanding of what it is that is refrained from being believed?

Comment: As you say, Ross assumes, and he doesn't get to assume for others. I wish he would engage Wittgensteinian answers to such questions, which were asked and answered long before him, but I see no trace of that in the paper. Instead we have dogmatic non-starters like "certain knowledge" presented as if they were gospel, 19th century ideas about "physical processes", and irrelevant digressions into "immateriality of thoughts". There are interesting arguments against Kripkenstein, see e.g. Miller's Philosophy of Language for detailed survey, Ross's isn't one of them, and it lacks any originality.

Comment: @Conifold Can you please answer the last question? What separates doubt from ignorance if not determined meaning? What does it even mean to say all meaning is indeterminate? Furthermore, how can one argue for such a position if meaning is required for any argumentation? What we're getting at is simply a clash in unclarified presuppositions. You mention Wittgenstein. What about him? Can you actually offer a clear answer besides "well, Ross assumes blablabla". Yeah, and you assume blebleble. The point is which assumption can be maintained by what is necesarry for any rationality whatsoever.

Comment: @Ovid: Wittgenstein's picture of language-as-use just outflanks the issue of whether determinacy or indeterminacy about meaning are somehow 'in the world' or not. It sounds like what Ross is doing is like the Degrees of Perfection argument for the existence of god: there's a thing out in the world, with degrees, & a highest level, because we can imagine it. No one buys that kind of reasoning anymore, it just doesn't make sense of language, or the mechanics of meaning. Wittgenstein is the dominant thinker on these issues, so read him, it's absurd to expect a complete summary of it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

"However, to 'understand what it is for thought to be determinate' requires that such a thought is itself determinate."  This does not seem to be the case.

Determinacy simply is not necessary to establish reference to a meaning or an argument.  We are perfectly happy with a range of potential references that share adequate traits to satisfy similar patterns and capture the relevant aspects of the meaning.

Arguing entirely from constraints, and relying entirely upon references as bundles of constraints is a perfectly reasonable way of establishing a consistent model between humans: we confirm shared perceptions all the time on that basis.  It is not necessary for our actual perceptions to literally refer to parallel experiences.  They don't.  We can still share a perceptual field.  In the same way, it is not necessary for arguments to construct similar effects upon individuals' thinking.  They very likely never do.  But we can still share a robust conceptual field.

In that way, we can have a cohesive notion of anything we could describe determinately, including determinacy, which is adequate to establish the understanding of humans about the meaning, even if it does not somehow construct a single point of reference in any semantic field.  And we are free to argue from that concept as long as the constraints faithfully express its structure.

If perception is indeterminate and provides the basis for our points of reference, and even our very idea of referring to things, it seems silly to consider *thought* determinate.

< Long aside if you think perception is determinate >

We have good evidence that perception works by pattern-matching, and not by assembly from elements.  The sense data is *not* collected and collated and then assembled into a cohesive model of the sensed world.  Instead, the model is constructed and reality is probed for confirmation of the presumed representation.  Only if the representation fails tests against reality is it altered.  Change-blindness, very hard to explain in a world where sensation is 'determinate', is the natural order of things.

We can verify that the information flows in this direction, out from the presumed model rather than in from the surface, by looking at the priming of responses to experiences like emotions or reflexes, which are planned for by our physiology too far ahead of the actual experience for the information to move the other direction, coming in from the environment.

This explains, among other things, why we think we can 'see around' the hole in our visual field imposed by the optic nerve site.  Its constant presence ensures that it never introduces contradictory information.  Similar logic explains why various other sensory illusions that appear in isolation do not really confuse us in real life.  But **it rules out the notion that we actually share internal models** of what we perceive.

< / Long aside >

One can argue from a mathematical point of view that thought must be determinate in some domain established as the factorization of the real domain through the filter of the patterns of constraints that allow things to match.  But the odds of those patterns actually establishing anything close enough to an equivalence relation are very low, and it seems almost guaranteed that they are not consistent.

So there is no good reason to think that the notion of determinacy is an aspect of thought, or that this matters.  It is a convenient simplifying fiction, but is neither sufficient nor necessary, and it seems inconsistent with the way a large part of our experience works.

Comment: It does analyse the argument he gives.  I have quoted the part it addresses, and I have flipped the flow over so that it converges, instead of starting from the motivation and working back toward the issue.

Answer (score 0):

User9166's answer seems to approach the analysis from the philosophy of mind invoking perception as a justification for rejecting the existence determinancy and relegating it to a nominalistic tool. An approach from the philosophy of language might bear some light.

The question of determinancy is one of determination, and simply, it might simply best to expose the inherent either-or presumption of the question. Meaning is not either determinate or indeterminate, but rather, is always underdetermined. Thus, the question itself presupposes black and white thinking. This is consistent with the general notion of [fallibilism](https://iep.utm.edu/fallibil/) that seems to characterize in sophisticated language a very common-sensical view of human cognition: it's imperfect, but it works.

Consider some areas of underdetermination:

- In science, underdetermination of scientific theory was the death knell for logicist, deductivist attempts to reduce scientific activity to certain, formal methods. That is, scientific observation is inherently psychological in some regard, and choosing the correct theory is one that has no simple, algorithmic solution.
- In mathematics, statistical methods like polynomial regression lead to undetermination of solution. Constraints must be applied to general solutions. The statistical nature of quantum physics has taken these statistical explanations and made them part of the very uncertainty of the nature of physical reality itself.
- In computer science, underdetermination of meaning has implications in correctness of proof, since according to the philosophy of design, the very notion of creating and using rules seems subject to Kripke's skeptical paradox. The resolution offered by Kripke is one of normativity. Behavioral conventions, then, serve as a basis for interpretation.
- In linguistics, language seems on paper to suffer translation indeterminacy which leads to startling arguments that translation is not possible. And yet it happens everyday. 'Weltanschauung' and 'worldview' may not be exactly the same, but they're close enough given the constraints of goal-oriented communication and collective intentionality.

And why does these philosophical claims of indeterminacy occur over and over again? Because if one disembodies the logical from the psychological, the normative abilities of the agent operating in society are stripped from the discourse. But continental philosophers and post-Wittgensteinian philosophers who pay attention to the private language argument, semantic family resemblance, and the language-game have the arguments necessary to show that practically speaking, pragmatics matters. And pragmatics means things work in the real-world because context the agent operates in resolves indeterminacy time and time again. Many Continental philosophers don't even bother themselves with indeterminacy, and semioticians like CS Pierce (I suspect) would never elevate claims of the existence of indeterminacy to anything more than a prima facie argument.

> that a rejection of determinancy presupposes a conception of determinancy itself, so that in denying thought to be determinate one must understand what it is for thought to be determinate.

So, I think it's fair to say that many philosophers would reject this issue entirely, and see this question dissolved by the fact that the indeterminacy-determinacy dichotomy is fundamentally limited in much the same way the rational-empirical and analytic-synthetic distinction are.